# Recursive search for a file extension in ftp server

Tags: shell, recursion, ftp

I need to find files with extension `.shp`, and then get his paths, in the subfolders of this ftp server ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/ how could I do this through shell scripting?

Comment: Can't you use the recursive option on whether?

Comment: ops, I meant "wget" not "whether" (autocorrect)

Comment: @LucasMation I knew about the recursive but not the filter which i found here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53397/wget-how-to-download-recursively-and-only-specific-mime-types-extensions-i-e I wil try it later, but I just want the paths not download it yet, I dont want the entire data which I think is huge, just want some specific states which I don't know the pattern yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JaderMartins, if all you want is the path of all `.shp` files, you can use `lftp` for that:

```
lftp ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/
du -a > allpaths.txt
```

Now you have a local file named `allpaths.txt` with all the files and folders and their sizes. So `grep` it for files ending with `.shp`:

```
grep -i \.shp$ allpaths.txt
```

The `du` command will probably take some time to send all the file names. You can also use `tail` in another terminal to keep looking for `.shp` files while `du` is running:

```
tail -f allpaths.txt | grep -i \.shp$
```